# Grouping rows and adding sequence numbers in SQL SELECT statement without modifying table

Tags: sql, database

Assume that we have a table like this:

| Date | User | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | X |
| 2021-01-05 | A | Y |
| 2021-01-11 | A | Z |
| 2021-01-01 | B | X |
| 2021-01-16 | B | Y |
| 2021-01-01 | C | X |
| 2021-01-02 | C | Y |
| 2021-01-03 | C | Z |
| 2021-01-10 | D | X |
| 2021-01-15 | D | Y |

I want to group each user by its date and item and add sequence number DURING QUERY, NOT BY MODIFYING TABLE. For a user, the sequence number of the item with the first date should be first. The number should start all over again for each new user. I want to retrieve data like this:

| Date | User | Item | Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | X | 1 |
| 2021-01-05 | A | Y | 2 |
| 2021-01-11 | A | Z | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | X | 1 |
| 2021-01-16 | B | Y | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | X | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | C | Y | 2 |
| 2021-01-03 | C | Z | 3 |
| 2021-01-10 | D | X | 1 |
| 2021-01-15 | D | Y | 2 |

Is it possible? Can I retrieve data like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `row_number()` does:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by user order by date) as seqnum
from t;
```

Comment: I also used row_number() but the key part that I missed is "partition by". Thanks!